# Скользящее окно на pandas аналогично SQL-запросу

Tags: sql, pandas

у меня есть датасет step_student, в котором есть столбцы:
step_id(номера шагов),
student_id(номера студентов),
res_bin (содержит 1 и 0 значения, описывающие успешность прохождения шага),
sub_time(временная метка подачи решения шага).
Примерно выглядит так:

| step_id | student_id | res_bin | sub_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1245678 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 1248754 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1247890 |

я хочу создать новый столбец diff_res, в котором будет содержаться информация о том, отличается ли текущее значение в столбце res_bin от последующего значения в столбце res_bin.
Причем границы окна формируются только на одинаковых step_id и student_id (считать разницу нужно только для одного и того же студента в рамках одного шага).
А также важно, чтобы при подсчете разности значений в res_bin значения были отсортированы по возрастанию времени отправки (sub_time)

В результате должно получиться вот это:

| step_id | student_id | res_bin | sub_time | diff_res |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1245678 | None |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1247890 | -1 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 1248754 | None |

То есть скользящее окно будет работать блоками, в которых:

- студент один и тот же
- шаг один и тот же
- время внутри окна отсортировано по возрастанию

сделать это в SQL довольно просто:

```
select *,
        (lead(res_bin)
        over(partition by student_id, step_id order by sub_time) - res_bin) as diff_res
    from  step_student
```

Но как сделать это в pandas ? не могу понять насколько широкий функционал у функции pandas.DataFrame.rolling(window =), мне кажется он очень усеченным в сравнении с аналогом SQL.

Кто знает решение?

Comment: как будто бы подойдет решение с предварительной группировкой, но оно не очень красивое:

step_student.groupby(['step_id', 'student_id'], as_index=False)\
     ['res_bin'].\
     rolling(window=2).\
     apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1] - x.iloc[0])